# row cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java, eclipse

```
public class Assignment1{ 
   public static void main(String[] args) {  
      final int MAX_ROWS = 5 ;   
      for(int row = 1; row<= MAX_ROWS; row++) ;  
      {for (int star = 1; star <= row ; star++); }
```

why eclipse told me ‘ row cannot be resolved to a variable ’  （the row in the last line)

Comment: Hint: in programming details matter. Even subtle things as where you place your ; characters!

Comment: Declare row = 1 before first for loop. Your row variable is local variable and scope of it is limited to only first loop. It is not visible to 2nd loop

Comment: You terminate your first loop, before the second begins. This might not be intended.

Answer (score 4):

```
 for(int row = 1; row<= MAX_ROWS; row++) ;
```

Remove ; after for

Answer (score 2):

because the semicolon at the end of the 1st for loop is killing the scope of the row variable..

```
 for(int row = 1; row<= MAX_ROWS; row++) ; // <-- remove that ;
```

Answer (score 2):

Thats because of the semi colon after for

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 final int MAX_ROWS = 5 ; 
for(int row = 1; row<= MAX_ROWS; row++) ;
 {
for (int star = 1; star <= row ; star++); 
}
```

The semi colon is causing for row loop to end, hence the scope of if is complete, so row is not visible in second for loop.
Remove the semicolon and code will work.

Answer (score 2):

You have a redundant (read: wrong) semicolon (`;`) after the first `for`. This semicolon terminates the `for`'s block, and since `row` is only defined **within** it, you get the error on the next block. Just remove it, and you should be fine:

```
public class Assignment1{ 
   public static void main(String[] args) {  
      final int MAX_ROWS = 5 ;   
      for (int row = 1; row<= MAX_ROWS; row++)
      // Semicolon removed here --------------^
      {
          for (int star = 1; star <= row ; star++); 
          // And you probably want to remove this ^
          // And have a sensible body in this loop too.
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look close

```
for(int row = 1; row<= MAX_ROWS; row++) ; <--
```

which is equal to

```
for(int row = 1; row<= MAX_ROWS; row++){
 }
```

The extra `;` caused to close the for loop context right away in that line. So the context of row ends in that line.

Remove that `;` . It should work.

Comment: Just wondering: wouldn't the sane thing be to make a comment and make a "close on typo" vote?

Comment: @GhostCat Nope. The OP have a basic misunderstanding of ;. If you look at his other loops, he did the same.

Comment: Yep; and we have a "typo" question that now has 6 or 7 answers ... for absolutely no good reason. A comment and a quick "close" would have served the *community* better ; imho.

Comment: @GhostCat Yes. Agreed, But just telling `remove ;` won't help I guess. Explaining why to remove `;` help is.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Assignment1{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        final int MAX_ROWS = 5 ;   
        for(int row = 1; row<= MAX_ROWS; row++){  
           for (int star = 1; star <= row ; star++){
                      //Now insert some printing codes here
            }
        }
     }
```

**You have inserted semi-colon after the for loop which terminates the loop there so just remove that and your code will work perfectly fine**